# How to Set a custom field "option set" in Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

How to Set a custom field "option set" in Dynamics 365?
This snipped is for retrieve,but for setting?

```
var _entityName = "systemuser"; //user
var fieldName = "new_officetype";  //option set field

RetrieveEntityRequest entityRequest = new RetrieveEntityRequest
{
    EntityFilters = EntityFilters.All,
    LogicalName = _entityName,
    RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
};

// Get the Response and MetaData. Then convert to Option MetaData Array.
RetrieveEntityResponse entityResponse = (RetrieveEntityResponse)_orgService.Execute(entityRequest);
EntityMetadata metadata = entityResponse.EntityMetadata;
PicklistAttributeMetadata picklistMetadata = metadata.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(attribute => String.Equals(attribute.LogicalName, fieldName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) as PicklistAttributeMetadata;
OptionSetMetadata optionsSetMet = picklistMetadata.OptionSet;
var optionlist = (from o in optionsSetMet.Options
                  select new { Value = o.Value, Text = o.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label }).ToList();
foreach (var item in optionlist)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Text + " " + item.Value);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of setting an option set using the late bound approach:

```
_Account.Attributes.Add(“accountcategorycode”, new OptionSetValue(2));
```

In the above example, _Account is an instance of Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity and OptionSetValue is also in the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk library.

For early bound, I use XrmToolkit proxy classes, which give you an enum for each option set, so setting an option set value looks like this:

```
 new_resulttype = eResultType.Integer;
```